# jQuery - keep added onclick css after page reload

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, refresh, reload

I added css by jQuery to my page to enable visitors changing the contrast by clicking button.

But I would like to keep css active after reloading the page (when contrast button is already clicked). I hope it is possible, because I didn't find any solution yet.

My code:

```
var applied = false;

$('.contrast-on').click(function() {
  if (!applied) {
    $('*').css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)').css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)').css('background-image', 'none');
    applied = true;
  } else {
    $('*').css('background-color', '').css('color', '').css('background-image', '');
    applied = false;
  }
});
```

It is important that visitor will not have to click contrast button every time on every pages/posts on my site.

Comment: Can you show us the whole stuff (html etc.)

Comment: @Beata I have shared the solution with cookie please check my answer..that will work with reload condition.Let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `localStorage` for this purpose.

```
var applied = localStorage.getItem("applied") == "true";
if (applied) {
  $('*').css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)').css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)').css('background-image', 'none');  
} else {
  $('*').css('background-color', '').css('color', '').css('background-image', '');
}

$('.contrast-on').click(function() {
  if (!applied) {
    $('*').css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)').css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)').css('background-image', 'none');
    applied = true;    
  } else {
    $('*').css('background-color', '').css('color', '').css('background-image', '');
    applied = false;
  }
  localStorage.setItem("applied", applied);
});
```

**Note:** this will  not save result for browser restart. If you want long-term solution, use DB or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined `var applied = false;`, every time you reload the page your variable will be reset to value `false`. To achieve what you mentioned you have to get this variable from database or your server side code and read the value of the variable for given user (i.e using ajax call) on page load.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use Session Storage : 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

You can use either localstorage to keep it even after the browser is closed or sessionstorage which keep infos until user closes the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HTML5 Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to achieve this. What this does is save data client-sided, which you can retrieve on every page load (e.g. your `document.ready function`).

You could do something like:

```
$('#yourButton').click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem("contrast", "your-css-class");
});
```

and on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".element-your-css-should-be-applied-to").addClass(localStorage.getItem("contrast"));
})
```

See [this fiddle to try it out!](https://jsfiddle.net/zvftk2r4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use css is better

```
.contrast-on-clicked{
    background-color : rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color : rgb(255, 255, 255);    
}
```

edit js

```
$('.contrast-on').click(function() {
  var applied = localStorage.getItem("contrast-clicked");
  if (applied != "true") {
    $('*').addClass('contrast-on-clicked');
    localStorage.setItem("contrast-clicked",true);
  } else {
    $('*').removeClass('contrast-on-clicked');
    localStorage.setItem("contrast-clicked",false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by cookie. as below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var applied = false;
    var isContrastOn = readCookie('is_contrast_on');
    if (isContrastOn) {
      $('*').css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)').css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)').css('background-image', 'none');
    }
    $('.contrast-on').click(function() {
      if (!applied) {
        createCookie("is_contrast_on", 1);
        $('*').css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)').css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)').css('background-image', 'none');
        applied = true;
      } else {
        $('*').css('background-color', '').css('color', '').css('background-image', '');
        applied = false;
      }
    });
  })
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    else
      var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
  }

  function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
        c = c.substring(1, c.length);
      if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0)
        return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
  }

  function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
  }
```

Comment: @Beata Local Storage will not help you when you will reload the page but this will work for you or you can manage same with session if you want do it at server side or from db also. Let me know if help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Cookie**    :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var applied = false;
var visited = getCookie("visited");
if (visited==1) {
    $('.contrast-on').css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)').css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)').css('background-image', 'none');
}

$('.contrast-on').click(function() {
    if (! applied) {
        $('*').css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 0)').css('color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)').css('background-image', 'none');
        applied = true;
        setCookie("visited", 1, 365);
    } else {
    $('*').css('background-color', '').css('color', '').css('background-image', '');
        applied = false;
        setCookie("visited", "", -1);
    }
});

function setCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}


</script>
```